# if:else not working with my matrix tag pair

Tags: matrix, ifelse

Maybe I am a moron, but i just can't get this to work. Iv anyone can help me... please do so before i start hurting myself... :p 
I'm working with EE 2.5.5 and Matrix 2.5.2.

I've got a channel called "**events**". 
A matrix field assigned to "events" called "**dates**" (minimum rows = 0). 
"Dates" has 3 colums, a date column called 'date', a text column called 'city' and a P&T Switch called 'confirmed'.

Each entry has either no date (=no row), one date oder multiple dates. Each  'date' can of course be „in the future“ or „in the past“ since past events don't get deleted.

I'm trying to put out a list of all entries in this channel and ONE date (if conditions are met).

1. If there is no date specified (=no row) in the matrix field: "**no date specified**"
2. If there ARE entries for dates:
   case 1: in the future, i need **the next upcoming date**
   case 2: all dates in the past, i need "**no date specified**" again

I have tried everything i can think of but it seems i am not able to use if:else  between my matrix tags...

**My approach:** 
Getting entries with no date is easy.

```
{if dates}
   do something...
{if:else} 
   no dates found
{/if}
```

So far, so good. But when i try to do

```
    {if dates}
       {dates search:date=">{current_time}" sort="asc" limit="1"}
          {if date} 
             {date format="%d.%m.%Y"} <!-- outputs next upcoming date if there is one -->
          {if:else} 
             no date specified <!-- THIS does not work. Should get triggered when there 
ARE rows in "dates" but all "date"-values are < current_time =  already happened,  -->
          {/if}
       {/dates}
    {if:else}
       no date specified <!-- no row -->
    {/if}
```

Any suggestions? 
I've spent 4 hours trying everything i could think of... still getting nowhere....

Comment: David, I'll read this in more detail in a bit and see how I can help - but I'd also recommend first upgrading to Matrix 2.5.3 just to rule out any fixed issues.  It's only a small upgrade.  I'll be digging into this this morning

Comment: I'm already on 2.5.3, upgraded EE and Matrix already to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely be to do with [parse order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf). Because you're using advanced conditionals they will be parsed late on and probably evaluated after Matrix conditionals are processed.

Give it a try with simple conditionals by just using {if} statements. So:

```
{if dates != ""}
   do something
{/if}
{if dates == ""}
   no dates found
{/if}
```

(Depending on what type of data is returned from dates you may need to experiment with your conditional checking. It could return a boolean for instance rather than a string)

The same applies to your nested if statement. Apply the same principle.

The above will be processed much earlier in the parse order and that will most likely make the difference.

Let me know what the outcome of that is.

Comment: But how can I accomplish my goal with just simple conditionals?

I'm not having any problems with {dates}, I can't get {date} to work. Since my matrix field can contain {date}'s in the past AND in the future, i need to construct a query to sort that out.

Like:

Are there {date}'s? 
No? "no dates". 
Yes? If there are, are any of them in the future? If yes, display the soonest date. If not, display "no dates".

I can't figure out how to do this with simple conditionals... sorry.

Comment: Negating logic. :) At this point it's just to test. If it works then you know it's parse order and the first point to figuring out a solution is to identify the problem. Start off simple with a conditional like that and see if that works first.

Comment: yeah i got that. but {if dates} dates! {if:else} no dates {/if} already works for me :)

Comment: my code looks like this atm:

`{if dates != ""}
  {dates search:date="IS_EMPTY" sort="asc"}
  EMPTY
  {/dates} 
  {dates search:date=">={current_time}" sort="asc" limit="1"}
    {date format="%d.%m.%Y"}
  {/dates} 
{/if}
{if dates == ""} 
  NO ROW
{/if}`

it works. except for entries with JUST dates in the past of course.

Comment: Have you tried just putting in {date} and {current_time} to ensure they're in the same time format - that may have implications to the search parameter.

Comment: Ah, OK I misunderstood that part. How about changing the inner nested conditional to something like this: http://pastie.org/7115932 ?

Comment: {date} and {current_time} both render als unix timestamp: `1364659206 and 1364245727` - the comparison works. it's just the fracking if:else that dosn't seem to work.

Comment: @Ian:

I've tried that before. The '{dates search:date=">{current_time}" sort="asc" limit="1"}' actually breaks the code and nothing renders. I'm not sure about what to put when into what kind of Brackets and what not. I'm starting to think that i don't really understand how matrix handels data at all.

Comment: At least we know both {date} and {current_time} both output the same Unix timestamp format. How about this: http://pastie.org/7123109

Comment: Basically that's the code I use atm. :)
I wrote my answer here: http://pastie.org/7123440

Comment: I'd just test the output again. Output {date} on it's own to see what is output on a filled and empty row. You're saying 'if {date}' but assuming it returns a boolean then it could also return true if it has an empty value as it may evaluate an empty string as true. Test the output of date first and let me know the output. On a side note I'm still not entirely clear why you can't strip out that extra if statement if it returns the same message as the outer one. That's why I stripped it down. But it's hard to fully understand the need when I only see a glance and not the fully picture.

Comment: i need the outer {if dates} because if there are now rows in the matrix field, i need to output "not dates".

the inner if might output the same but the query is completly different. i can't just throw out the inner if that outputs the same as the outer if, because there wouldn't be any output IF there are dates specified but all of them are in the past. 

Right now I'm not really sure there is a way to get this sucker to work since i can't use advanced conditionals. Simple conditionals just ... simply don't work here.

Answer (score 0):

The search: parameter mimics the EE search parameter.  That means it only searches Text Input, Textarea, and Drop-down fields ([search: parameter])[1](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name)

I see here that you're trying to search on a date type column.  It sounds like that may be the core problem.  If you run a few of these as plain tests against one of the supported fields, do you get more expected results?

Comment: Yes I know, I've read the search:fieldname documentation. The stragne thing is: It 'kind of' works. {if date} does indeed give the result I'd expect, {if:else} just doesn't get triggered if there is no entry > current_time. Since both values (date and current_time) are integer... is there any other way I could get this to work? 

My last resort would be to write the mySQL query myself.

Comment: It looks like I just can't use advanced conditionals... and without an if:else I'm not going to get the output I'm looking for.

Comment: David - I saw above that you were using the search: parameter - what is your code for just the conditionals, when not using the search: parameter? Given what you need to accomplish here, I also somewhat wonder if an add-on targeted at event handling might be more appropriate?